# What exactly is this lug for on a SATA cable?

Tags: sata, cable

On this SATA cable, for what is the lug on the one plug? I think the "lock" (that the physical connection is more stable) is managed by the silver metal. But the lug? I haven't any idea for what this should be in practice.

[image: sata cable with lock and lug]

Answer (score 2):

On the right angle connector, presumably to make it easier to hold and handle, though I've never seen one with that extension. Considering it's a low profile variant of SATA, it does seem a little odd.

Comment: IMHO: If you pull on the plug body it would twist the connector in the socket, the extension gives you a straight pull to remove it & reduces chance of damage to the socket.

Comment: Mine don't have the extention. Works fine. Thats the *obvious* purpose of it quite certainly.

Comment: @BrianA don't you still need to push up on the metal clip on the connector anyways?

Comment: Squeeze, actually